# AEM sightly not seeing model field from Java

Tags: aem, sling, sightly

I have a Java model I would like to use in my HTL. It looks something like this:

```java
public class MyModel {
    private Model model;

    ...

    public Model getModel() {return model;}
}

public class Model {
    private String myField;

    ...

    public String getMyField() {return myField;}
}
```

I try using it in my template like this:

```html
<sly data-sly-use.myModel="path.to.package.MyModel" />

<div data-sly-use.localModel="${myModel.model}">${localModel.myField}</div>
```

However when I try editing the page using this model I receive `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException`, no idea where from.
When I try changing `data-sly-use` to `data-sly-test` there's no exception, the page loads, however the div with the test does not show, so apparently the test returns false.
Does creating such model requires an additional configuration in AEM in order to use it?
The fields in my classes are currently being mocked, so there's no way they are null.

EDIT:
It works when I wrap the `Model` object inside `MyModel` in a list and use `data-sly-list` in the HTL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`data-sly-use` is intended for instantiating Use Objects, not for assigning variables; you should be using [data-sly-set](https://github.com/adobe/htl-spec/blob/master/SPECIFICATION.md#2212-set) instead.

Alternatively, you could just use `${myModel.model.myField}`.

Comment: Tried that, but still getting an `ArrayIndexOufOfBoundsException` in `AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:81`

Comment: A full stacktrace would help debug it

Comment: @MarcinZareba, could you also add the root stacktrace(s), ie `Caused by:`?

Comment: I wanted to, but it's not there - that's all I'm seeing on the page, well this and AEM's `Request Progress` but I guess it's not that relevant.

Comment: Funny thing - instead of `data-sly-use` or `data-sly-set` i directly invoked the model in the HTL so:
`<div>${myModel.model.myField}</div>`
and it worked... but why? Im working in a corporate AEM project, might be that some hooks underneath break the functionality - the stacktrace suggest something tagging-related.

Comment: Nesting like that is supported but I’m still puzzled by the error when using `data-sly-set`. The tagging filter seems like a red herring.

Comment: The full stacktraces should be available in `error.log`

Comment: Also nothing - it contains only the stack trace I've pasted, no root.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232506/discussion-between-vlad-and-marcin-zareba).